# Vertical align multiple lines including h1 and p elements

Tags: javascript, css, alignment, lines

I want to make my p text and h1 text both vertical align. 
I tried multiple solutions, like the table solution etc. 
Because I have a h1 and a p, it doesn't work for both the same.
Or only my p is vertical align, or my h1 is next to my p....

```css
#txtslide {
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100%;
}
}
#txtslide h1 {
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
#txtslide1, #txtslide2, #txtslide3 {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33%
}
#txtslide1 {
    border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
#txtslide p {
    font-family:'Source sans pro';
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding-left: 15%;
    width: 80%;
}
#txtslide3 p #txtslide1 p {
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    padding-left: 18%;
    width: 64%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
#txtslide1 h1 {
    padding-left: 15%;
}
#txtslide img {
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-left: 18%;
}
#txtslide3 p {
    padding-top:15%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtslide">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="txtslide1">
            <img src="images/kaarten.png" />
             <h1>titeln</h1>

            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="txtslide2">
             <h1>Kop</h1>

            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="txtslide3">
            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not so clear to me. Can you post an image about expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33%
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}

p {
    font-family: 'Source sans pro';
    font-size: 2vw;    
    text-align: center;   
    
}

img {
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
   margin: auto auto;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">  
    <div id = "txtslide1" >
        <img src = "images/kaarten.png" />
  <h1>titeln</h1>
        
       <p>
    text text
   </p>
 </div>
 </div> 
    
<div class = "container">                    
  <h1>title 2</h1>
   <p>
   text text
   </p>
 
</div>
         
<div class = "container">    
 
       <h1>title3</h1>
     <p>
   text text
     </p>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tidied up your css and html structure slightly.

```css
#txtslide {
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width:100%;
}
img {
    border:1px solid black;
}
.container {
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
}
.txtSlide p, .txtSlide h1 {
}
.txtSlide {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height: 500px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
.txtSlide p {
    font-family:'Source sans pro';
    font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtslide">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="txtSlide" id="txtslide1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
             <h1>titeln</h1>

            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="txtSlide" id="txtslide2">
             <h1>Kop</h1>

            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="txtSlide" id="txtslide3">
            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` in parent and `display: table-cell` on child's:

```css
#txtslide {
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#txtslide h1 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
}
#txtslide1,
#txtslide2,
#txtslide3 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 33%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#txtslide1 {
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
#txtslide p {
  font-family: 'Source sans pro';
  font-size: 1vw;
  padding-left: 15%;
  width: 80%;
}
#txtslide3 p #txtslide1 p {
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  padding-left: 18%;
  width: 64%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
#txtslide1 h1 {
  padding-left: 15%;
}
#txtslide img {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-left: 18%;
}
#txtslide3 p {
  padding-top: 15%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtslide">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="txtslide1">
      <img src="images/kaarten.png" />
      <h1>titeln</h1>

      <p>text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="txtslide2">
      <h1>Kop</h1>

      <p>text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="txtslide3">
      <p>text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Also did this one worked?

Comment: What do you mean? I have looked but I have no idea.

Comment: No, because I still have no vertical center. :( See the link (http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=3531q2v&s=8) , I'm coming closer!